# External booting of STM32F427 from EEPROM

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom

I am working on Stm32f427. I want to interface EEPROM with this microcontroler for external booting. The external booting options mentioned in referance manual are from system memory and SRAM. Please tell me how to interface EEPROM with this microcontroller. Can I use SRAM for booting through EEPROM?

Comment: you have to live within what the microcontroller will use.  I assume you mean you want to have an external eeprom with code on it to boot from?  I would have to read the docs, but you already have them in front of you, but I assume you would need some code in flash, that copies the eeprom to sram then branches to that code.   or you have code in flash that copies the eeprom to another bank of flash, then branches to that.

Comment: dont necessarily know why they would have that boot from sram option, certainly for pre-silicon simulation.  but some parts dont expose boot1 anyway so you only care about boot0 modes, the user program or the bootloader basically.   you could perhaps boot with the bootloader, shove the program into ram, change the straps and reset, not sure if that hoses the ram or not.  probably better to just have the applicaiton on flash load into other parts of flash or sram and branch.  or just use the onboard flash that is what it is there for

Comment: thank you very much